# Text file To CSV

Tags: java

I have read a Text file but i need to convert it into a CSV file. Below is the code i used to read the text file. Could i please get some help to add on to this in order to convert it to the CSV file?

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
                throws FileNotFoundException {
                File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Nathan\\Desktop\\ECLIPS WORK SPACE\\HomeWork3\\seed.txt");
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
                while((sc.hasNext())) {
                sc.useDelimiter(", " + "    ");
                System.out.println(sc.next());
                }
                sc.close();
            }
```

}

The sample data:

Sample Data:Price, cheap, good value, reasonable price, great for the price, very cheap, not pricey, affordable
Cleanliness, clean place, clean, very clean, good hygiene, good cleanliness, clean surroundings
Location, great location, nice location, great view, nice view, safe, very safe location

The first column is a "Seed ID" the second column is the "Category ID" The category names are the first words in each row of the text and the third row is a polarity number, since all of these are positive 1.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDK51.png

I am not allowed to post pictures yet. so i hope the description i gave will work in case the link above dose not work.

Comment: I removed the `plsql` and `sql` tags, since they are obviously unrelated to the question.

Comment: Please show us sample data from this file, and also include what the CSV output should look like.

Comment: Don't call `useDelimiter` inside the loop.

Comment: I don't see any relationship between your description and image.